# Motherboard don't recognize new installed CPU Model?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, cpu, motherboard, bios

**WINDOWS 7 ULTIMATE**

I have an abit nf-m2 nview motherboard with a previous AMD Athlon 64 X2 5200+ which works fine and dandy. Recently I swapped out a few things including CPU to an Athlon 64 X2 5050e Brisbane, the system still runs fine, but cpu is reported as Athlon 64 X2 Unknown model. I am thinking a bios flash, but would like to get some opinions first as to what other possible reasons it could be?

Things I've tried:

1: Ran driver update from device manager, but didn't find anything. Says K8 is the best thing windows could find and is already installed.

2: Uninstalled the CPU chipset driver from device manager and restarted.

In case anyone is wondering, these are swapped items:

500W PSU -> 300W PSU

65W CPU -> 45W CPU

7200RPM HDD -> 5400RPM HDD

4x1 GB DDR2 -> 2x2 GB DDR2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the processor is of a newer generation, I would try to upgrade the BIOS as you said.

Comment: Wouldn't do any harm if i just left it alone? I mean it's just a model reporting unknown which i already know the model anyway.

Comment: Technically, if it is working, it is working - and I only usually suggest people upgrade BIOS as the last thing to try... however, as it is reporting unknown, there may be updates available that "unlock" new features. I am more of an Intel guy though so I can't say for certain - in your situation, I personally would upgrade (or at least read the last few release notes!)

Comment: Normally I wouldn't hesitate, but my current BIOS is in 2007, and their last updated BIOS is 2008, so in this situation, I don't even know if upgrading BIOS would help much if the 5050e was one of the last AMD X2. Will probably try when I have more time, but thanks for the info.

Comment: Upgrade the BIOS, if the CPU is not being recognized correctly then you run risk of sporadic timing (and other) issues. If the BIOS upgrade doesn't cause it to be recognized properly then your motherboard doesn't officially support that CPU. You may want to consider upgrading it with the old CPU in.